# Determine the flow and amplitude equation for thermal energy (with Del operator)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, heat, vectors, maxwell-equations, calculus

It is a question vector calculus and Maxwell's laws. I put it this way.  Let's say, we are working in a $3$-Dimensional space ( e.g $x\cdot y\cdot z = 4\cdot3\cdot2$, a certain room/class of that size ) .

Within this room, the heat obey a certain  equation  ( for e.g. $T = 25 + 5z$ ) .We know that heat flows from higher temperature regions to lower temperature regions. With this information in mind

> How could I be able to determine the amplitude and the direction of travel of the thermal energy with the [Del operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del)?

I'm not looking for a definitive response, but an equation that could give me potentially the result for the amplitude and the direction. I also want to know if thermal energy follows a loop pattern within my room (and be able to explain it mathematically by using the del operator once again of course)?

You can find the lecture source [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/41111655/Differential-Calculus-of-Vector-Fields).

From those, we are able to get the Amplitude:

For one dimensional heat flow, we have $q= k \dfrac{T_2-T_1}{L}$ , where $T_1$ and $T_2$ are terminal temperatures and $L$ is the length of the material. Switching to $3$-D spaces, we need to look at the fourier system of the heat transfer before proceeding further. $\dfrac{q_x}{A}= - K \dfrac{dT}{dx}$. So integrating we obtain $$\dfrac{q_x}{A}\large \int_{0}^{L}  \ dx= -k \int_{T_1}^{T_2}  \ dT.$$

So given that the heat flow ( rate of conduction ) in the $3$-D space  $(x,y,z)$ is given by the following equation $$ q= - k \nabla T = - k \bigg( \hat{i} \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x}+\hat{j} \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial y}+\hat{k} \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial y}\bigg).$$The negative sign, there indicates the transfer of heat from one place to another. So we can simply substitute the heat equation in the place of $T$ and compute the partial derivatives to get the rate of flow of heat.

What about the direction?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you already wrote the answer, $\bf{\nabla} T$ is actually a vector that points in the direction where the temperature rises the steepest. So minus this vector is the direction where the temperature falls the steepest.